# Problems when creating and getting the values of dynamic controls in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my first question in stackoverflow so apologies if there are any mistakes, missing information, etc. and do notify me if so.

I have an asp.net page that requires a set of `LiteralControl`, `TextBox`, and `DropDownList` to be dynamically added when a `Button` (named addMoreButton) is clicked. I have used ViewState to preserve the required values.

```
protected void addMoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    //The rowAmount is already initialized outside the scope of this function. It is incremented by 1 and will be used to determine the Textbox and DropDownList IDs        
    rowAmount++;        

    //The viewState ArrayList would be added to the ViewState
    //For each row of webcontrols (literalcontrols, textbox and dropdownlist) added, an ArrayList newState will be added to viewState
    ArrayList viewState;
    ArrayList newState = new ArrayList();

    //If the ViewState is empty, an empty ArrayList will be initialized to be added later
    if (ViewState["pageViewState"] == null)
    {
        viewState = new ArrayList();
    }
    //If it isn't, the ArrayList from the existing viewState will be retrieved. Additional values will be added.
    else
    {
        viewState = (ArrayList)ViewState["pageViewState"];
    }

    //Before displaying, the necessary texts for the LiteralControl are stored into a variable as they also need to be stored into a viewstate
    string text1 = "Unit of item sold: &nbsp";
    string text2 = "&nbsp of amount: ";
    string text3 = "&nbsp with price per unit of: &nbsp";
    string separator = "<br />";

    //The texts and the rowAmount are added to the newState ArrayList
    //Different datatypes are used, which will be explained in the next code block.
    newState.Add(text1);
    newState.Add((float)rowAmount);
    newState.Add(text2);        
    newState.Add(rowAmount);
    newState.Add(text3);
    newState.Add((double)rowAmount);
    newState.Add(separator);

    //The newState ArrayList is added to the viewState ArrayList
    viewState.Add(newState);

    //The final viewState ArrayList is added to the ViewState        
    ViewState.Add("pageViewState",viewState);                   
}
```

Now I've tried to dynamically create the controls by adding them to a `Panel` called rowPanel.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Getting the viewState 
    ArrayList viewState = (ArrayList)ViewState["pageViewState"];

    //The page will be populated with the dynamically created controls if the ViewState isn't null.
    if (viewState != null)
    {
        //viewState is an ArrayList containing an ArrayList...
        foreach (ArrayList i in viewState)
        {
            //...and the ArrayList contains items of several data types, different data types create different controls.
            foreach (object o in i)
            {
                //String = LiteralControl           
                if (o.GetType().ToString() == "System.String")
                {
                    rowPanels.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(o.ToString()));
                }                    
                //Integer = textbox
                else if (o.GetType().ToString() == "System.Int32")
                {              
                    TextBox newBox = new TextBox();

                    //Setting the properties
                    newBox.Text = "amountTextBox" + o.ToString();
                    newBox.ID = "amountTextBox" + o.ToString();
                    newBox.Width = 28;

                    //Adding the textbox into rowPanels                                             
                    rowPanels.Controls.Add(newBox);                        
                }
                //Single = DropDownList
                else if (o.GetType().ToString() == "System.Single")
                {                 
                    DropDownList newDDList = new DropDownList();
                    newDDList.ID = "unitDropDownList" + o.ToString();

                    //Adding the textbox into rowPanels                                                                      
                    rowPanels.Controls.Add(newDDList);
                }
                //Double = another TextBox
                else if (o.GetType().ToString() == "System.Double")
                {
                    TextBox newBox = new TextBox();
                    newBox.ID = "priceTextBox" + o.ToString();
                    newBox.Width = 90;

                    //Adding the textbox into rowPanels                                                              
                    rowPanels.Controls.Add(newBox);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of testing, I've added a button with an OnClick Event as following

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print(rowPanels.Controls.Count.ToString());
}
```

After adding several rows of controls and performing Button1_Click above, the debugger displays only 1, despite the dynamically added controls displaying on the page.

On the other hand, if I perform the dynamic control addition in Page_Load instead of Page_PreRender, the debugger returns the correct value. However, I have to press the addMoreButton twice in order for it to show up (this is the main reason why I switched to Page_PreRender)

I know that the problem is due to page lifecycle, but I can't figure out in which lifecycle stage do I need to do the dynamic addition in order to retrieve the values of my controls properly. Can someone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I print the amount of Controls inside rowPanel for testing only. In actual use, what I want to do is to retrieve the values inside each dynamically created dropdownlists and textboxes.

I will try to use ViewState again for this. I will post results once I'm finished.